# Squats: Should your knees never go past your toes?

Tags: squats

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the key to avoid injury when squatting with your body weight?](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/2959/what-is-the-key-to-avoid-injury-when-squatting-with-your-body-weight)

I've heard that when you are doing squats, your knees should not go past your toes. However, [two hundred squats](http://www.twohundredsquats.com/what.html), is telling me that I should go down until my legs are parallel to the ground. I can't go parallel without my knees going past my toes. Should I stop my knees going past my toes, or should I go all the way down?

Answer (score 1):

The advice to not let your knees track past your toes is specifically for loaded squats. In unloaded "air" squats, where you don't have a barbell or similar implement involved, I think it's okay to let your knees track past your toes.

That said, the two hundred squats and related programs are okay, but a little silly. Their instructions say:

> Lower your body to a position where your thighs are almost parallel to the floor.

This is a half-squat. A program where you focus on getting two hundred half-squats lacks balance, among other things. The bodyweight resources in [the answers to this question](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/3714/bodyweight-exercise-resources) would probably be much more productive.

Comment: I was planning to combine the squats program with the pushup program, but now I'll check out Convict Conditioning