# I can only do body weight squats with proper form - how to compensate?

Tags: squats, legs, ectomorph

I only do body weight squats as whenever I use a barbell or dumbbell my form goes crooked i.e I shift on the right side while going down; probably because I am a tall guy.  I've tried researching but couldn't solve it.  I know squats are important but I just cannot get it.

Here is my leg day routine in order:

- 3x12reps free squats
- 3x walking lunges
- 3x leg press
- 3x step ups
- 3x leg extensions
- 3x hamstring curls

I try to make it up by going heavy on other exercises 
What can I add to my routine to make up for lack of squats? 
I am an ectomorph.

Comment: Is it possible you're just doing too much weight when you try to squat? Have you tried with just the empty barbell to get the form down and work up from there?

Comment: When I started squatting I used to put 2 small "slabs" under my heels, it helped me keep my balance since you tend to put your weight on your tips as you go down, eventually I removed them since I got used to the proper form, hopefully you might give it a try OP

Answer (score 3):

**First things first**

While I know what you mean by "ectomorph", you should know that this is a term related to the debunked myth of somatotypes.

Read second paragraph here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Somatotype_and_constitutional_psychology

**Do squats!**

Rather than not doing weighted squats, you should learn how to do it. Giving up such a fundamental exercise is never the answer.

I wrote an answer [here](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/26140/squats-technique-flat-feet/26141#26141) about overcoming certain squat related imbalances.

As you don't give any details about how your form breaks under the weight, I can't write a more detailed answer. But your gym should have employees whose sole purpose is to help you with this. Ask them for a form check.

Adding a bunch of tiny exercises is never a good replacement for one huge compound exercise. It's usually only something bodybuilders do to get that perfect symmetry. And even then, they do squats too.

Comment: https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=h6nxexHhvxA look at this video ihave the same problem but mine doesnt seem to fix

Comment: @sharingan - Elliott Hulse knows what he's talking about when it comes to correcting squat and deadlift form. I'd suggest you do as he suggests to that guy, which is to do some overhead squats (or front squats as I suggested in the other answer), and some sumo deadlifts.